# How to cluster Categorical/Ordinal Survey Data

Tags: clustering, survey, hierarchical-clustering

I have customer survey response data from Surveymonkey. I want to know what the best method would be for similarity analysis in order to create customer segments.

Most of this data is categorical "Yes/No" or Ordinal, eg. Favorite Social Media Platform "Facebook, Twitter, Instagram"

I wish to group similar responses together in order to come up with personas.
Can Hierarchical Clustering be a good approach for this?